# Material Design Lite and Infinite Scrolling script conflict

Tags: javascript, material-design, infinite-scroll, material-design-lite

I am using Material Design Lite (http://www.getmdl.io/started/) and Infinite Scroll script ( https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll ) on my Wordpress website. When I use both scripts, infinite scroll doesnt work. But it works when I delete Material Design Lite script. I suppose there is some conflict between these script. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to fix it?

Comment: Sure I did. I tried edit this code https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: do you have any updates? same problem. thanks